# Parse page windows-1251 to utf-8. can't grab text

Tags: php, parsing, iconv

I want to grab names for my product from table.

But I can't grab names with  cyrillic characters.

For parsing I'm using ganon.

When I try to output array with names, all value which must contain  cyrillic  characters are empty. Why?

Please help me to fix it.

```
    $url = "http://www.plati.ru/asp/block_goods_s.asp?id_r=0&id_s=252900&sort=name&page=1&rows=10&curr=EUR&lang=ru-RU&rnd=1544554";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/7.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $redir = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    curl_close($ch);

    $html = str_get_dom($result);

    foreach ($html('.link_good_tab') as $element) {
        $temp = str_replace("\xA0", ' ', $element->getPlainText());
        $products[] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($temp, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $temp);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($products);
    echo "</pre>";
```

This is result

```
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
    [5] =>
    [6] =>
    [7] =>
    [8] =>
    [9] =>
    [10] => C&C: Red Alert 3 - Uprising (Origin/RegFree/Multilang)
```

Comment: Do not use `mb_detect_encoding` and set encoding that you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know the encoding, just set it yourself instead, and you can also use `mb_convert_encoding()`. Example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.plati.ru/asp/block_goods_s.asp?id_r=0&id_s=252900&sort=name&page=1&rows=10&curr=EUR&lang=ru-RU&rnd=1544554');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$html = str_get_dom($result);
foreach ($html('.link_good_tab') as $element) {
    $temp = str_replace("\xA0", ' ', $element->getPlainText());
    $products[] = mb_convert_encoding($temp, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($products);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my computer, [mb_detect_order()](http://php.net/mb_detect_order) returns this:

```
array (
  0 => 'ASCII',
  1 => 'UTF-8',
)
```

Output in your system is possibly similiar (i.e., does not include Windows-1251 at all).

Not sure why you need to auto-detect encoding if you apparently already know which one it is but, if you need to, you should use the `Content-Type` header returned by remote server or, at most, the corresponding `<meta>` tag.